# $P_n$ is a.s. to P, $Q_n$ is L1 to Q. $P(P_n \neq Q_n) \leq 1/n$. Is $P=Q$ a.s.?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

$\left\{P_{n}\right\}_{n=1,2, \ldots}$ and $\left\{Q_{n}\right\}_{n=1,2, \ldots}$ are two sequences of r.v.s. For every $n$ , $\mathbb{P}\left(P_{n} \neq Q_{n}\right) \leq 1 / n . P_{n} \stackrel{\text {a.s.}}{\rightarrow} P$ and $Q_{n} \stackrel{L^{1}}{\rightarrow} Q$. Can we conclude that $P=Q$ a.s.?

Is it right?

Answer (score 3):

Consider a subsequence of $P_n$, $P_{mn} = P_{mn} - Q_{mn} + Q_{mn}$

Answer (score 1):

Convergence in probability and convergence in $L^{1}$ both imply a.s. convergence for a subsequence. Since $\mathbb P(|P_n-Q_n| > \epsilon) \leq \frac  1n$ it follows that $P_n-Q_n \to 0 $ in probability. Choose a sub-sequence of $(P_n-Q_n)$ which tends to $0$ (so that $Q_n \to P$ as. along this subsequence) and then choose  a further subsequence along which $Q_n \to Q$ a.s.. It is now clear that $P=Q$ a.s..

Comment: Very helpful! Thanks al lot!

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Note that
$$\mathbb P(|P-Q| > \epsilon) \leq \mathbb P(|P - P_n| > \epsilon/3) + \mathbb P(|P_n - Q_n| > \epsilon /3) + \mathbb P(|Q_n - Q| > \epsilon/3).$$
Letting $n \to \infty$, the right-hand side tends to $0$ (because both a.s. and $L^1$ convergence imply convergence in probability). This implies that $P=Q$ a.s.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!! But I am still confused $\mathbb{P}(|P-Q|>\epsilon) \rightarrow 0$ is the definition for convergence in probability, how can we know it converges a.s?

Comment: The question wasn't about convergence but rather a.s. equality. I showed that for all $\epsilon > 0$, $\mathbb P(|P-Q| > \epsilon) = 0$. Since this holds for **all** $\epsilon > 0$, it follows (formally, using continuity of $\mathbb P$) that $\mathbb P(P \neq Q) = 0$. In other words, $\mathbb P(P=Q)=1$. In other words, $P=Q$ a.s.

Comment: Note that when you write $\mathbb P(|P-Q| > \epsilon) \to 0$, the left-hand side of the arrow doesn't depend on $n$. So this is really just the same as writing $\mathbb P(|P-Q| > \epsilon) = 0$.

Comment: Got it! Thanks again.